# Why is this allocation not well done?

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, c99, opaque-types

I have `point.h` and `polygon.h` files, with their associated `.c` files. In `point.h`

```
// point.h
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

typedef struct Point point;

point *point_alloc(void);
void *point_free(point *);
void *point_init(point *, float, float);
void *point_print(const point *);
float point_get_x(const point *);
float point_get_y(const point *);
void *point_set_x(point *, float);
void *point_set_y(point *, float);

#endif
```

In `point.c`, I have

```
// point.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "point.h"

#define GET_VALUE_ERROR (2L)

struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

point *point_alloc(void)
{
    point *pt = malloc(sizeof *pt);

    if(NULL == pt)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate point.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        return pt;
    }
}

void *point_free(point *pt)
{
    if(NULL == pt)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not free point.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        free(pt);
        pt = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
}

void *point_init(point *pt, float x, float y)
{
    if(NULL == pt)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot initiate point.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        pt -> x = x;
        pt -> y = y;
        return NULL;
    }
}

void *point_print(const point *pt)
{
    if(NULL == pt)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot print point.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Point at (%f, %f)\n", pt -> x, pt -> y);
        return NULL;
    }
}

float point_get_x(const point *pt)
{
    if(NULL == pt)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get point.\n");
        return GET_VALUE_ERROR;
    }
    else
    {
        return pt -> x;
    }
}

float point_get_y(const point *pt)
{
    if(NULL == pt)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get point.\n");
        return GET_VALUE_ERROR;
    }
    else
    {
        return pt -> y;
    }
}

void *point_set_x(point *pt, float x)
{
    if(NULL == pt)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get point.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        pt -> x = x;
        return NULL;
    }
}

void *point_set_y(point *pt, float y)
{
    if(NULL == pt)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot get point.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        pt -> y = y;
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

while in `polygon.h` I have

```
// polygon.h
#ifndef POLYGON_H
#define POLYGON_H

typedef struct Polygon polygon;

polygon *polygon_alloc(unsigned);
void *polygon_free(polygon *);
void *polygon_init(polygon *, unsigned, float, point *);
void *polygon_print(const polygon *);
unsigned polygon_get_nside(const polygon *);
void *polygon_set_nside(polygon *, unsigned);
point *polygon_get_centre(const polygon *);
void *polygon_set_centre(polygon *, point *);
point *polygon_get_vertex(const polygon *, unsigned);
void *polygon_set_vertex(polygon *, unsigned, float, float);

#endif
```

and in `polygon.c` I have

```
// polygon.c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "point.h"
#include "polygon.h"

#ifndef M_PI
    #define M_PI (3.14159265358979323846264338327950288)
#endif

#define GET_NSIDE_ERROR (2U)

struct Polygon
{
    unsigned nside;
    point *centre;
    point **vertices;
};

polygon *polygon_alloc(unsigned nside)
{
    if(nside == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot have a 0-sided polygon.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        polygon *poly = malloc(sizeof(*poly));

        if(NULL == poly)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate polygon.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            poly -> nside = nside;
            poly -> centre = point_alloc();
            if(NULL == poly -> centre)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate polygon centre.\n");
                free(poly);
                poly = NULL;
                return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                poly -> vertices = malloc(nside * sizeof(point*));
                if(NULL == poly -> vertices)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate polygon vertices.\n");
                    free(poly -> centre);
                    poly -> centre = NULL;
                    free(poly);
                    poly = NULL;
                    return NULL;
                }
                else
                {
                    for(unsigned i = 0; i < nside; i++)
                    {
                        poly -> vertices[i] = point_alloc();
                        if(NULL == poly -> vertices[i])
                        {
                            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate node %u.\n", i);
                            for(unsigned j = 0; j < i; j++)
                            {
                                free(poly -> vertices[j]);
                                poly -> vertices[j] = NULL;
                            }
                            free(poly -> centre);
                            poly -> centre = NULL;
                            free(poly -> vertices);
                            poly -> vertices = NULL;
                            free(poly);
                            poly = NULL;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return poly;
    }
}

void *polygon_free(polygon *poly)
{
    if(NULL == poly)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot free polygon.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        if(NULL == poly -> centre)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot free polygon centre.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            free(poly -> centre);
            poly -> centre = NULL;

            if(NULL == poly -> vertices)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cannot free polygon vertices.\n");
                return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                for(unsigned i = 0; i < poly -> nside; i++)
                {
                    if(NULL == poly -> vertices[i])
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot free vertex %u.\n", i);
                        return NULL;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        free(poly -> vertices[i]);
                        poly -> vertices[i] = NULL;
                    }
                }

                free(poly -> vertices);
                poly -> vertices = NULL;
            }
        }

        free(poly);
        poly = NULL;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void *polygon_init(polygon *poly, unsigned nside, float radius, point *centre)
{
    if(NULL == poly)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Polygon not existing.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else if(NULL == centre)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Polygon centre not existing.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        polygon_set_nside(poly, nside);
        polygon_set_centre(poly, centre);

        for(unsigned i = 0; i < poly -> nside; i++)
        {
            float angle = (1 + 2 * i) * (M_PI / poly -> nside);
            float x = radius * cos(angle);
            float y = radius * sin(angle);
            polygon_set_vertex(poly, i, x, y);
        }

        return NULL;
    }
}

void *polygon_set_nside(polygon *poly, unsigned nside)
{
    if(NULL == poly)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set polygon number of sides.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        poly -> nside = nside;
        return NULL;
    }
}

void *polygon_set_centre(polygon *poly, point *centre)
{
    if(NULL == poly)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set polygon number of sides.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        poly -> centre = centre;
        return NULL;
    }
}

// Rest of implementation
```

Apparently, the allocation and/or free of the polygon is not correct. To see this, I wrote this `main.c` reading

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "point.h"
#include "polygon.h"

int main() {
    unsigned nside = 3;
    float radius = 1.0;

    point* centre = point_alloc();
    point_init(centre, 0.0, 0.0);

    polygon* poly = polygon_alloc(nside);
    polygon_init(poly, nside, radius, centre); // this one is a problem
    polygon_print(poly);

    polygon_free(poly);
    point_free(centre);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

compiled using the command `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -std=c99 .\point.c .\polygon.c .\main.c -o .\main.exe`, I have a a "red cross in my IDE (I use `VSCode`), as illustrated here in the picture (which indicates that something is wrong) and I do not know neither from where it comes, nor how to solve it?
[image]

***EDIT***

I corrected the allocation/freeing function thanks to the answer below, and was able to find that the problem is caused by the `polygon_init` function, but I cannot pinpoint what is wrong there?

Comment: You are missing a `#include "point.h"` in `polygon.h`.

Comment: You are missing the implementation of `init_polygon()` in the above.

Comment: It's a little odd that you define `EXECUTION_OK` as `0U` when you are expected to return a (signed) `int`.  stdlib.h provides `EXIT_SUCCESS`.

Comment: I don't know anything about vscode so does it give you a green dot for a program that just `return EXECUTION_OK;`?

Comment: It's not wrong but setting pointers to NULL as in  `free(poly); poly = NULL` adds noise to your code. Also if you `return` don't do an `else` block just have it at the same level as the previous `if`.

Comment: You should prefer returning type specific pointers instead of .void *`.

Comment: `free(NULL)` is well defined.    It seems counter-intuitive to make `free_point(NULL)` an error.

Comment: If you want to ensure that you do not have a programming error and are passing NULL to the functions when you don't expect to be, it might be appropriate to change the error message from "Could not free point. Aborting" (which is a lie, because the program does not immediately abort) to something like "Unexpected NULL passed to 'free'".  Better yet, just write `assert(pt != NULL);`.  (The assertion is *not* error checking, and do not mistake it for that.)

Comment: @AllanWind I tried to follow the recommendations of [this link](https://cyber.gouv.fr/publications/regles-de-programmation-pour-le-developpement-securise-de-logiciels-en-langage-c) (in French tho', as the English version at [this link](https://cyber.gouv.fr/en/publications/rules-secure-c-language-software-development) is currently broken). This explain the lines like `NULL == pt` and putting the address of a freed pointer to `NULL` (to avoid dangling pointers) and all the like.

Comment: @AllanWind i use `void* ` as most return type because if an allocation fails, it should return `NULL`, so that the rest of the program can execute "normally" and free everything that was correctly allocated. This explains why I also return `NULL`, even if everything goes well.

Comment: @aheuchamps The advise you have read is not necessarily wrong.  The reason why they do the fixed value before the variable is to catch the error `NULL = pt` which is a syntax error while `pt = NULL` is an assignment.  The thing is compilers warn you about this by asking you to write`if((pt = NULL))` if that is really want an assignment.  Your program crashed instead of using a dangling pointer so there is some value in setting free'ed pointers to NULL.  In `free_polygon()` the object is no longer alive but you don't set caller's value to NULL which require you to pass in `polygon **poly`.

Comment: @aheuchamps I was referring to `free_polygon()` which returns NULL in all cases.  It's better to just not return anything then so caller doesn't have to worry if they need to capture the return value or not.

Comment: @AllanWind *The thing is compilers warn you about this*  That warning is generally **worse** than useless.  It's worse because you *think* that warning protects you, but if you write a complex `if` statement with an accidental assignment in it instead of a comparison, that warning won't fire.  So when you need it most - in complex `if` statements where the bug is very hard if not impossible to spot, you get no warning even though you believed you were protected.  That's **worse** than useless.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I rarely make that mistake so it's a minor inconvenience for me to placate the compiler. Also, I only ever use assignments for simple expressions, but I appreciate that you are worried about a bug in a complex expression.  It will take a bit of effort to rewrite my brain to reverse the arguments and I haven't been bit hard enough to make it worth it.  Thanks for sharing your point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program segfaults in `free_polygon()` because you free the `vertices` array before each of its `verticies[i]` element:

```
                free(poly -> vertices);
                poly -> vertices = NULL;

                for(unsigned i = 0; i < poly -> nside; i++)
                {
                    if(NULL == poly -> vertices[i])
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot free vertex %u.\n", i);
                        return NULL;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        free(poly -> vertices[i]);
                        poly -> vertices = NULL;
                    }
                }
```

In general you want to free resources in reverse order of how they are allocated (free `vertices[i]` before `vertices`).  Any error in `free_polygon()` may result in memory leaks.  For example if `poly->vertices[i] == NULL` then we don't free remaining `poly->verticies[i]`, `poly->vertices`, `poly->centre` or `poly`.  As your `alloc_polygon()` takes care of partial constructions is probably ok but it's a risky design:

```
void* free_polygon(polygon* poly) {
    if(NULL == poly) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot free polygon.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    if(NULL == poly->vertices) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot free polygon vertices.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < poly->nside; i++) {
        if(NULL == poly->vertices[i]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot free vertex %u.\n", i);
            return NULL;
        }
        free(poly->vertices[i]);
        poly->vertices[i] = NULL;
    }
    free(poly->vertices);
    if(NULL == poly->centre) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot free polygon centre.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    free(poly->centre);
    free(poly);
    return NULL;
}
```

Other suggestions:

1. As `free_polygon()` always return `NULL` consider changing it's return type to `void`.
2. With experience `!poly` is easier to read then `NULL == poly`.
3. `alloc_polygon()` is quite complicated; consider designing the allocation and free function as a matching pair so you can always call `free_polygon()` on a partially constructed object by initializing variables with NULL, `calloc` instead of `malloc()` of `verticies` and free resources in reverse.  I routinely use `goto` for cleanup chains but if you have qualms you can duplicate those two lines instead in each error case.  Compilers (at least gcc) will warn you if you miss a variable initialization before a `goto` which I find helpful.
4. As your `poly` object's lifetime expired after a call to `free_polygon()` I never bother setting any of the variables to `NULL`.  That said it may help you catch a use after free defect.
5. Consider using a namespace prefix, i.e. `polygon_alloc()` instead of `alloc_polygon()`.
6. Prefer `polygon *poly` to `polygon* poly`.  It avoids confusion if you ever declare two pointers on one line.

```
polygon *polygon_alloc(unsigned nside) {
    polygon *poly = malloc(sizeof *poly);
    if(!poly) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate polygon.\n");
        goto err;
    }
    poly->nside = nside;
    poly->vertices = NULL;
    poly->centre = alloc_point();
    if(!poly->centre) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate polygon centre.\n");
        goto err;
    }
    poly->vertices = calloc(nside, sizeof *poly->vertices);
    if(!poly->vertices) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate polygon vertices.\n");
        goto err;
    }
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < nside; i++) {
        poly->vertices[i] = alloc_point();
        if(!poly->vertices[i]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate node %u.\n", i);
            goto err;
        }
    }
    return poly;
:err
    polygon_free(poly);
    return NULL;   
}

void polygon_free(polygon *poly) {
    if(!poly) return;
    if(poly->vertices)
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < poly->nside; i++)
           free(poly->vertices[i]);
    free(poly->vertices);
    free(poly->centre);
    free(poly);
}
```